# Comparison test for ${{{\int_{{1}}^{{\infty}}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}}\,{d}{x}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> Using the comparison test determine whether the following integral will converge.
>
> $$\displaystyle{{{\int_{{1}}^{{\infty}}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}}\,{d}{x}}}$$

I've struggled with this for a good while now... Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: $\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\sim\dfrac{1}{x}$. So integral diverges. If you need strict comparsion, just write definition of limit.

Comment: Hint: If $x\ge1$ then $1-e^{-x}\ge 1-1/e>0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac  {1 -e^{-x}} x \geq \frac 1 x -\frac  1 {x^{2}} \geq \frac  1 {2x}$ for $x >2$.